# How are weak references in a reference counted system implemented?

Tags: algorithms, compilers, memory-management

When reference counting is used for automatic memory management (e.g. Objective C or Swift), it is well know that “loops” give problems.   E.g.

```
class Car
{
     Engine engine;
}
class Engine
{
     Car installedIn;
}
```

[Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011575/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weak-reference-and-an-unowned-reference) (along with other systems) avoids this problem by allowing the reference from the `car` instance to the `engine` instance to be weak.   So that the `engine` instance does not keep the `car` instance alive, and when the `car` instance is freed, then the reference from the `engine` instance is set to null.

What are the standard ways of implementing this within a runtime/compiler?

Comment: The short answer is that in a reference-counted system weak references are simply not counted.  Which is actually a simpler/base/primitive case of "normal" assignment.  Normally in a reference-counted environment the runtime/compiler has to inject instructions to increment the reference-count for a given object every time a new pointer to it is assigned (and to decrement the count when the pointer goes out of scope).  With a weak reference, those extra instructions can simply be omitted.

Comment: @aroth, that is the easy bit, the hard bit is that NULL (not a reference to a freed object) is returned when the week reference is accessed.

Comment: Yes.  You'll need someone with detailed internal knowledge of the compiler/runtime to answer that part.  All I can do is speculate.  For instance, perhaps the runtime maintains a map (or similar structure) that associates the address  of each allocated object with the addresses of all the in-scope pointers that refer to it, and when an object's reference count reaches 0 it's removed from the map and any remaining in-scope pointers are set to `nil`.  That might work, but no idea if that's akin to what it actually does.

Comment: Mike Ash has a fantastic write up on how these are implemented for Swift: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-12-11-swift-weak-references.html